# How to read text from a file in NASM and get each line comma seperated?

Tags: assembly, text-files, nasm

Okay so I'm working on a project based on MikeOS and I'm attempting to get a comma separated list from a text file. For example if the text file had "hello" on line 1 "world" on line 2 and "!" on line 3, I want a return of "hello,world,!" Is this possible, and if so how can I do it. Im relatively new to NASM but I have a basic understanding of it. Any help would be appreciated :D

```
pop si

push si

mov bx, si
mov ax, si
call os_string_length

mov si, bx
add si, ax

dec si
dec si
dec si

mov di, txt_ext
mov cx, 3
rep cmpsb
jne bad extension

pop si

mov ax, si
mov cx, 32768
call os_load_file

call os_clear_screen
```

(at this point in the code now that the text file is loaded into ram, I want it to retrieve the comma separated list I mentioned for use in a list box)

Comment: os_load_file and this --> http://mikeos.sourceforge.net/handbook-appdev-asm.html#syscalldisk would be a good starting point.

Comment: so far in my code, the file is loaded into ram, I just dont know how to take text from the file.

Comment: "loading a file into ram" is another way of saying that "copying the _content_ of that file where I want it", so you already have the text. Also, add your code to the question

Comment: okay I added the code to my question.

Comment: So now all you have to do is to replace every '\n' with ','

Comment: How would I do that, and then how would I move the list to one of the registers?

Comment: thanks so much! and yeah my knowledge on assembly is pretty limited as of right now

Answer (score 0):

Given your comments I assume you have a very basic knowledge of assembly in general, so let's start with some C code. You have already loaded the file somewhere into RAM, so you just have to create the comma-separated list by replacing newlines with commas; in code:

```
void to_list(char *text) {
    while(*text != '\0') {
        if(*text == '\n')
            *text = ','
        text += 1;
    }
}
```

Now, long time has passed since I have last programmed in x86 assembly, but a line-to-line translation would be something along the lines of:

```
to_list:                    ; text is passed in the si register
    pusha
    mov     bl, 2ch         ; ASCII code for ','

to_list_loop:
    mov     al, [si]        ; load the character
    cmp     al, 0           ; end of string?
    je      to_list_ret

    cmp     al, 0dh         ; newline?
    jne     to_list_inc
    mov     [si], bl        ; if yes, replace with a comma

to_list_inc:
    inc     si              ; and go to next character
    jmp     to_list_loop

to_list_ret:
    popa
    ret
```

Comment: Hint: But some textfiles(example for DOS) uses CR(0dh) + LF(0ah) for a new line.

Comment: @DirkWolfgangGlomp Right. This is an exercise for the reader :p